# Django REST Framework setting to change the auto added 'Id' to 'djangoID'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, primary-key

I'm happy to let DRF add an 'ID' column to my model if no primary key is defined.

Is there a way in settings to make this name more appropriate?

eg 'ID' would actually be 'djangoID'

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I will **not recommend** doing something like that. But if you want to change you can do it by specifying a **custom primary key**.

Just specify `primary_key=True` on one of your fields(here for example `djangoID`). If Django sees you’ve explicitly set **Field.primary_key**, it will not add the automatic `id` column.

As it will not automatically add `id` column you've effectively **renamed** it.